# How can one fetch the authorized users along with their details in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project, which I'm currently using with android. I need to programmatically fetch details of the users authorized along with the UID, Email, etc. Exactly the way it is shown in firebase (with the search), this web portal will be given to the vendor or the person using it to verify the user's authenticity.

I've attached the screenshot from Firebase, I'm hoping to replicate it the same way with the search. If this is possible, how do I go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to list users from an Android app, using only the Firebase Authentication SDK.  You can [list users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), but that can only be run on a backend you control, using service account credentials for your project.

It might be easier if you store user info in a database, to be queried by client code, rather than try to have your app try to access auth data directly.